# Collection isn't being saved in mongodb (Story collection from the mongoose populate documentation)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, database

The below code gives me this error:

```
  console.log("The creator is %s", story._creator.name)
                                        ^

  TypeError: Cannot read property '_creator' of null
```

---

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/pop2");


var personSchema = Schema({
    _id : Number,
    name : String,
    age : Number,
    stories  : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Story"}]
})


var storySchema = Schema({
    _creator : {type : Number, ref : "Person"},
    title : String,
    fans : [{type : Number, ref : "Person"}]
});

var Story = mongoose.model("Story", storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);


var aaron = new Person({_id : 0, name :"Aaron", age : 100});

aaron.save(function(err){
    if(err) return handleError(err)

    var story1 = new Story({
        title : "Once upon a timex.",
        _creator : aaron._id
    });

    story1.save(function(err){
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        console.log("saved") //doe snot output saved
    })
})

Story.findOne({title : "Once upon a timex."})
        .populate("_creator")
        .exec(function(err, story){
            console.log(story)// I get an output of null in console could be from this
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            console.log("The creator is %s", story._creator.name)}) // error from above



app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on 3000")
})
```

I'm just trying to follow the [populate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). so I want a solution that goes with that demo. I can't find what im missing.

When I do `show collections` I only see `people` and `system.indexes` collection not stories collection

EDIT :: I put the following inside the aaron.save() in the else part and I got an error

`{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: pop2.people.$_id_  dup key: { : 0 }]name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index`

```
    Story.findOne({title : "Once upon a timex."})
            .populate("_creator")
            .exec(function(err, story){
                // console.log(story)
                if(err) 
                    console.log(err);
                else{
                    console.log("mine : ",story)
                    console.log("The creator is %s", story._creator.name)
                }

            })
```

I figured that since it said "duplicate" I should drop the database and start the server again and I got the document. so that was good. But I tried to restart the server to save it again and I got a duplicate error again. now I need to drop the collections again. Why am I getting this duplicate error. If I just re-save normal docs I don't get this error.

Comment: Have you tried this : keep the `story1` and `story1.save` outside of  `aaron.save`? It worked for me (but I had to keep a simple handleError function)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the trick.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/pop2");


var personSchema = Schema({
    _id : Number,
    name : String,
    age : Number,
    stories  : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Story"}]
})


var storySchema = Schema({
    _creator : {type : Number, ref : "Person"},
    title : String,
    fans : [{type : Number, ref : "Person"}]
});

var Story = mongoose.model("Story", storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);


var aaron = new Person({_id : 0, name :"Aaron", age : 100});

aaron.save(function(err){
    if(err) return handleError(err)    
});

var story1 = new Story({
    title : "Once upon a timex.",
    _creator : aaron._id
});

story1.save(function(err){
    if(err) return handleError(err);
    console.log("saved")
});

Story.findOne({title : "Once upon a timex."})
        .populate("_creator")
        .exec(function(err, story){
            console.log(story);
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            console.log("The creator is %s", story._creator.name)})



app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on 3000")
});
```

Just check it out and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ill try that. While you were answering I got sum positive results by myself but sometimes I had a duplicate error. I wrote about it in an edit to the question. I'm wondering why I got that error .

Comment: This looks like it works. Still wondering why after I restart the server I get the duplicate error. And why the mongoose documentation had wrong information. I tried doing it the way it's in the demo and it didn't work. Why does that happen? anyways thanks.

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using??

Comment: No the mongoose version... not express?

Comment: "mongoose": "^4.3.7" my bad

Comment: Well I understood that, the error is happening when you try to save aaron to the database. And I think this is the issue related to that error : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2284. Hope it helps

Comment: now I see the error. it was because I didn't change the _id. It was always 0 when I saved it again.so that caused the duplicate error. usually when I test I have the _id be a random ObjectId. Thanks for your help. but one last thing about the documentation did I do something wrong or is the documentation not accurate. The way it showed to do all that stuff inside  `aaron.save(function (err) {` was confusing and wrong wasn't it? any advice for future reading of documentation?

Comment: Actually Im also new to this, the solution to this was purely guess work. The idea came as, usually you save one thing after another and not in the callback functions. Im sorry that I cannot give you any advice regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code, it works.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test'); 
var personSchema = new Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = new Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

//saving refs
var aaron = new Person({ _id: 0, name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  var story1 = new Story({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // thats it!
  }).then(function(){
    Story.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' })
        .populate('_creator')
        .exec(function (err, story) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('The creator is %s', story._creator.name);
        // prints "The creator is Aaron"
        });
    });
});
```

Basically saving is async. When you are calling Story.findOne the story did not get persisted yet